# How to get Collection using only collection name in Meteor 1.3?

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

In my project I'm using package which needs collection name to do some search inside collection. I just migrated into Meteor 1.3 and now this package doesn't work.

In the code package use something like:

```
const search = (collection_name) => {
   let collection = this[collection_name]
   ...
}
```

Now collection is not in global scope anymore.
I could add my collection there doing `global[collection_name] = Collection` in my `lib/collections.js`, but I'd rather like to fix package to be more flexible and Meteor 1.3 compatible.

Are there any possibilities how to get Mongo Collection if you know only collection name?

Comment: I believe you can do `window[collectionName]`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20785981/2805154

Comment: No, you can't. I mean it will not work on server, that's why I mentioned `global`.

In Meteor 1.3 you have to add then into global space manually, which is not good solution. That would force each Meteor 1.3 app creator (who is using my package) to add their Collections into global space manually. And main idea of using ES6 modules is to avoid globals as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sashko recommendation I looked at  https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances and then to `lai:collection-extensions` and here is how I solved it:

```
import { CollectionExtensions } from 'meteor/lai:collection-extensions'

let registered_collections = {}
CollectionExtensions.addExtension(function (name, options) {
  registered_collections[name] = {
    name: name,
    instance: this,
    options: options
  };
});

export function getCollectionByName(collecion_name) {
    return registered_collections[collecion_name].instance
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using what seems to be a private api that may change without notice as suggested by Archimedes, I recommend creating a global object to hold your collections.  The meteor docs specifically state:

`Generally, you'll assign Mongo.Collection objects in your app to global variables. You can only create one Mongo.Collection object for each underlying Mongo collection.`

So if you have a `Collections` global, you can easily access the collection in question via `Collections[name]`.  Of course you do want to limit your globals, so if you do currently have a global for your application, just give it a property to hold your collections.  The following is a common pattern that you can adapt to your needs, whether your collections are located in a single file or seperately.

```
app = app || {};
app.collections = {
    // collections here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution would not work, because I need it in package and don't want to force other app crested to force using one or other style of how to put collections into global name space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following technique

```
Meteor.default_connection._mongo_livedata_collections.users.find({}).fetch()
```

Just replace users with whatever collection you have.

https://forums.meteor.com/t/es6-global-collection-variables/22392/2?u=trajano

Comment: This returns the underlying collection not the Meteor.Collection, so an insert to this doesn't work properly. I.e. It appears on client but isn't sent to server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic (in client code):

```
Meteor.connection._stores['tasks']._getCollection()
```

For more info checkout:

[meteor/meteor#5845](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/5845) (initial attempt Dec 2015)

[meteor/meteor#6160](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/6160) (fixed Feb 2016)

Or if you prefer public API and don't mind another dependency use `mongo-collection-instances` as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '_stores' of undefined` for this :(

Comment: Sorry about that, check your Meteor version as this was only just added in Dec 2015, but had to be fixed in Feb 2016, I'll update answer with links.

Comment: It's Meteor 1.3.3.1

Comment: Oh sorry this is for the client code only it seems.

Comment: Then this solution isn't good fit. I need something what I can use in methods on server. So my chosen solution with `import { CollectionExtensions } from 'meteor/lai:collection-extensions'` looks like best solution for now.